# Covert UTC Date String to SQL Timestamp using Java 8

Tags: java

I have a Date String in ISO format with Time Zone. I have to convert it into  Timestamp with +/- Zone into time using Java 8.0
E.g.

`2016-10-14T10:12:18.000+02:00` needs to be converted to `2016-10-14T08:12:18.000+00:00` or `2016-10-14T8:12:18.000Z`

```
String utcDate = "2016-10-14T10:12:18.100+02:00";
ZonedDateTime result = ZonedDateTime.parse(utcDate, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME);
System.out.println("Parsed: " + result);
```

Output:

```
Parsed: 2016-10-14T10:12:18.100+02:00
```

It doesn't add the zone +02:00 to Date.

Comment: For a start, I think you've misunderstood what "UTC" means - it's not a *format*... it's a frame of reference, mostly used for time zones. The string "2016-10-14T10:12:18.000+02:00" has an offset of 2 hours from UTC.

Comment: My Bad. I mean ISO format with time zones. I need to convert it to UTC with +/- offset.

Comment: @AtulKumar Please edit your Question to fix your mistake, and add clarity. Please explain what you mean by "SQL Timestamp" as your example code seems unrelated.

Answer (score 1):

Well currently you're not doing anything to convert the value - you're using a `ZonedDateTime`, so it's preserving the time zone (at least, the offset) that was provided. (I'd use `OffsetDateTime` for this rather than `ZonedDateTime`, as you don't actually have a time zone.)

You could either use [`withZoneSameInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#withZoneSameInstant-java.time.ZoneId-):

```
ZonedDateTime utc = result.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

Or just convert to an `Instant`:

```
Instant instant = result.toInstant();
```

(and then format appropriately, of course).